# Sorting in TreeView

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have Tree View in my UI. I want to sort by descending order.
but I got Some error

```
C:\Users\misu01\PycharmProjects\opcua\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/misu01/PycharmProjects/opcua/ListView2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/misu01/PycharmProjects/opcua/ListView2.py", line 128, in <module>
    listbox = MultiColumnListbox(root,element_header,element_list)
  File "C:/Users/misu01/PycharmProjects/opcua/ListView2.py", line 25, in __init__
    self._build_tree()
  File "C:/Users/misu01/PycharmProjects/opcua/ListView2.py", line 63, in _build_tree
    command=lambda c=col: treeview_sort_column(self.tree,c,False))
  File "C:\Users\misu01\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\ttk.py", line 1305, in heading
    return _val_or_dict(self.tk, kw, self._w, 'heading', column)
  File "C:\Users\misu01\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\ttk.py", line 299, in _val_or_dict
    res = tk.call(*(args + options))
_tkinter.TclError: Invalid column index car
```

I have tried with `get_child()` method to short it

Any help regarding this.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as tkFont
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

class MultiColumnListbox():
    """use a ttk.TreeView as a multicolumn ListBox"""

    def __init__(self,root,elementheader,elementlist):
        self.tree = ''
        self._root = root
        self.element_header= elementheader
        self.element_list = elementlist
        self._setup_widgets()
        self._build_tree()

    def _setup_widgets(self):
        win2 = Toplevel(self._root)

        win2.resizable(width=0, height=0)
        element_header= ['car', 'repair']
        message = "This is the child window"
        Label(win2, text=message).pack()
        new_element_header = ['1st', '2nd']

        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(win2, columns=new_element_header, show="headings", selectmode='browse')
        self.tree.pack(side='left')
        # container = ttk.Frame()
        # container.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

        # treeScroll = ttk.Scrollbar(win2)
        # treeScroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

        self.tree.heading("1st", text=element_header[0])
        self.tree.heading("2nd", text=element_header[1])

        vsb = ttk.Scrollbar(win2,orient="vertical",
                            command=self.tree.yview)
        vsb.pack(side='left', fill='y')

        hsb = ttk.Scrollbar(win2,orient="horizontal",
                            command=self.tree.xview)
        self.tree.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set,
                       xscrollcommand=hsb.set)

    def _build_tree(self):
        for col in self.element_header:
            self.tree.heading(col, text=col.title(),
                command=lambda c=col: treeview_sort_column(self.tree,c,False))
            # adjust the column's width to the header string
            self.tree.column(col,
                width=tkFont.Font().measure(col.title()))

        for item in self.element_list:
            self.tree.insert('', 'end', values=item)
            # adjust column's width if necessary to fit each value
            for ix, val in enumerate(item):
                col_w = tkFont.Font().measure(val)
                if self.tree.column(self.element_header[ix],width=None)<col_w:
                    self.tree.column(self.element_header[ix], width=col_w)


def treeview_sort_column(tv, col, reverse):
    l = [(tv.set(k, col), k) for k in tv.get_children('')]
    l.sort(reverse=reverse)

    # rearrange items in sorted positions
    for index, (val, k) in enumerate(l):
        tv.move(k, '', index)

    # reverse sort next time
    tv.heading(col, command=lambda: \
               treeview_sort_column(tv, col, not reverse))





def sortby(tree, col, descending):

    data = [(tree.set(child, col), child) \
        for child in tree.get_children('')]
    data.sort(reverse=descending)
    for ix, item in enumerate(data):
        tree.move(item[1], '', ix)
    # switch the heading so it will sort in the opposite direction
    tree.heading(col, command=lambda col=col: sortby(tree, col, \
        int(not descending)))

# the test data ..

if __name__ == '__main__':
    element_header= ['car', 'repair']
    element_list = [
        ('Hyundai', 'brakes'),
        ('Honda', 'light'),
        ('Lexus', 'battery'),
        ('Benz', 'wiper'),
        ('Ford', 'tire'),
        ('Chevy', 'air'),
        ('Chrysler', 'piston'),
        ('Toyota', 'brake pedal'),
        ('BMW', 'seat')
    ]

    root = Tk()
    listbox = MultiColumnListbox(root,element_header,element_list)
```

but now I modified the code like that:-

```html
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as tkFont
import tkinter.ttk as ttk




class MultiColumnListbox():
    """use a ttk.TreeView as a multicolumn ListBox"""

    def __init__(self,root,elementheader):
        self.tree = ''
        self._root = root
        self.element_header= elementheader
        self._setup_widgets()




    def _setup_widgets(self):
        win2 = Toplevel(self._root)
        win2.geometry('650x250')

        win2.resizable(width=0, height=0)
        message = "Read General"
        Label(win2, text=message).pack()
        new_element_header = [self.element_header[0], self.element_header[1]]

        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(win2, columns=new_element_header, show="headings", selectmode='browse')
        self.tree.pack(side='left')
        self.entry = tk.Entry(win2,bd=10)
        self.entry.pack()
        self.button = tk.Button(win2,text = 'Search',command = self.search).pack()

        self.tree.heading(self.element_header[0], text=self.element_header[0])
        self.tree.heading(self.element_header[1], text=self.element_header[1])

        vsb = ttk.Scrollbar(win2,orient="vertical",
                            command=self.tree.yview)
        vsb.pack(side='left', fill='y')

        hsb = ttk.Scrollbar(win2,orient="horizontal",
                            command=self.tree.xview)
        self.tree.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set,
                       xscrollcommand=hsb.set)

    def search(self,item = ''):
        print("hihihi")

        children = self.tree.get_children(item)
        for child in children:
            text = self.tree.item(child,'text')
            if text.startswith(self.entry.get()):
                self.tree.selection_set(child)
                print("Hi1")
                return True
            else:
                res = self.search(child)
                print("child:",child)
                print("child:", res)

                print("Hi2")
                if res:
                    return True



    def _build_tree(self,element_list):
        print("I am here")
        self.tree.delete(*self.tree.get_children())
        for col in self.element_header:
            self.tree.heading(col, text=col.title(),
                command=lambda c=col: treeview_sort_column(self.tree,c,False))
            # adjust the column's width to the header string
            self.tree.column(col,
                width=tkFont.Font().measure(col.title()))

        for item in element_list:

            # children = self.tree.get_children(item)
            # print(children)
            self.tree.insert('', 'end', values=item)
            # for child in children:
            #     if child == item :
            #         exit()
            #     else:
            #         self.tree.insert('', 'end', values=item)




            self.tree.insert('', 'end', values=item)
            # adjust column's width if necessary to fit each value

            for ix, val in enumerate(item):
                col_w = tkFont.Font().measure(val)
                if self.tree.column(self.element_header[ix],width=None)<col_w:
                    self.tree.column(self.element_header[ix], width=col_w)







def treeview_sort_column(tv, col, reverse):
    l = [(tv.set(k, col), k) for k in tv.get_children('')]
    l.sort(reverse=reverse)

    # rearrange items in sorted positions
    for index, (val, k) in enumerate(l):
        tv.move(k, '', index)

    # reverse sort next time
    tv.heading(col, command=lambda: \
               treeview_sort_column(tv, col, not reverse))





def sortby(tree, col, descending):

    data = [(tree.set(child, col), child) \
        for child in tree.get_children('')]
    data.sort(reverse=descending)
    for ix, item in enumerate(data):
        tree.move(item[1], '', ix)
    # switch the heading so it will sort in the opposite direction
    tree.heading(col, command=lambda col=col: sortby(tree, col, \
        int(not descending)))
```

but I got another error. I can see there are multiple entry of same entry in my tree view.
I attached here picture of that
How do I check if the item and it's value are present in the Tree view and equal before insert it.

MY calling functionality for this :-

```html
 listbox = MultiColumnListbox(root,header)


                def every(delay, task):
                        next_time = time.time() + delay
                        while True:
                                time.sleep(max(0, next_time - time.time()))
                                try:
                                        task()

                                except Exception:
                                        traceback.print_exc()
                                next_time += (time.time() - next_time)

                def callreadgeneral():
                        elementlist = []
                        for idxNo in df.index:
                                value = self.comm_object.readgeneral.readnodevalue(idxNo)
                                tagname = df.iloc[idxNo, 0]
                                print(f" {tagname} value is : {value}")
                                item = tagname,value
                                elementlist.append(item)

                        print(self._elementlist)



                        if elementlist == self._elementlist:
                                print("hi")
                                elementlist.clear()


                        else:
                                listbox._build_tree(elementlist)
                                self._elementlist.clear()
                                self._elementlist.extend(elementlist)
                                elementlist.clear()     # listview._build_tree(car_list)


                threading.Thread(target=lambda: every(1, callreadgeneral)).start()
```

Comment: The error is telling you that `car` is not a valid name of a column. That seems to be true since you're creating columns named `1st` and `2nd`.

Comment: @Bryan , Could you please help me to find the way how to serach item in treeview.Actually  what happen right  now same item entry tree view.I want to prevent that before I entry to it

Comment: I have changed the code like that:- win2.resizable(width=0, height=0)
        message = "This is the child window"
        Label(win2, text=message).pack()
        new_element_header = [self.element_header[0], self.element_header[1]]

        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(win2, columns=new_element_header, show="headings", selectmode='browse')
        self.tree.pack(side='left')

        self.tree.heading(self.element_header[0], text=self.element_header[0])
        self.tree.heading(self.element_header[1], text=self.element_header[1])
but now I can see

Comment: Presently I face items are inserted in tree view even if it is presented in tree view .actully in my project , I have to run  def _build_tree(self) method in while loop.So  what I found that there are multiple same data entry in tree view.So I want to  check item is present in tree view before insert

Comment: calling functionality:-

Comment: Your question is very confusing. You have three large blocks of code. Please try to reduce the code down to a [mcve] and be sure to ask a single question about that code.

Comment: Hello Sir,Sorry for the inconvenience.I will change the block content to make you understand